# Implement browser in windows form using awesomium

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, awesomium

I"m using [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) to try and implement webpages inside my windows form application.

I've used the the awesomium .NET samples but I just don't get the my tab with my homeurl.

When I run my project the status bar is floating inside my form and nothing else happens.

Anyone know where I can get a tut on how to do this or know what could be the problem?

```
    public Laboratory() {
        WebCoreConfig webConfig = new WebCoreConfig() {
            SaveCacheAndCookies = true,
            HomeURL = "http://www.google.com",
            LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose
        };

        // Using our executable as a child rendering process, is not
        // available when debugging in VS.
        if (!Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName.EndsWith("vshost")) {
            // We demonstrate using our own executable as child rendering process.
            // Also see the entry point (Main function) in Program.cs.
            webConfig.ChildProcessPath = WebCoreConfig.CHILD_PROCESS_SELF;
        }
        WebCore.Initialize(webConfig);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region methodes

    #region OpenTab
    internal WebDocument OpenTab(string url = null, string title = null) {
        WebDocument doc = String.IsNullOrEmpty(url) ? new WebDocument() :
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(title) ? new WebDocument(url) : new WebDocument(url, title);
        doc.Show(dockPanel);

        return doc;
    }
    #endregion

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        this.OpenTab();
    }
```

[image: Windows form application]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've redone the left panel completely and used the other example that was with the download, that works like a charm. It's very basic but that'll do for now.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem but i devised a work around for the problem . I implemented the main browser engine that needs to be rendered on every tab (WebDocument Page as per the example) as a user control . Then i used a DockPannel in the mainForm .

So i create an instance of the user control and then add this to an instance of the DockPannel and thus it creates a tab with the required structure .

In case you have still not found a solution or have problems , please leave down a comment and i'll put in some code to help you .